# Split into list of data frames by column index

Tags: r, split

Is there an easy way in base R to split a data frame into a list of data frames based on an index factor levels (taken from another data frame)?

For example,

```
x = data.frame(num1 = 1:26, let = letters, num2 = 10:35, LET = LETTERS)
ls = list(x[, 1:2], x[, 3:4])
```

But lets say we had an index indicating factor levels for columns, can split be used?

```
indx = c(1,1,2,2)
? split(x, indx)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be the `default` method of `split`

```
out <- split.default(x, indx)
identical(ls, setNames(out, NULL))
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't even realize there was a "split.default" :) it would help if it could be mentioned at least under "See also"...